# How to mock a mounted partition in Python

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I'm working on a task that operates on a mounted partition when it has reached a certain percentage used, i.e. when 90% of the parition has been allocated, perform task X.

In order to test this, i'd like to be able to stub out a volume with a given size, so I can fill it with garbage up to the point that task X is carried out, so I can make sure it's doing what it's supposed to do. Is this even possible? I'm using python 2.7 on linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to said with out your code, but you can mock the function used to retrived disk spaces and assign it a value higher than 90 %. Then test your task X.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll see if I can work that in, if not, i'll update the post with the relevant code in question, thanks :)